# The Media Queries That I am Using Do Not Make My App Responsive?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm building a pretty straight forward weather app. I'm trying to make the app, mobile responsive. However, the media queries I add do not resize the app when the screen is smaller.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="weather_wrapper">
    <div class="weatherCard">

      <div class="currentTemp">
        <p class = "help">Click on the temp to change units</p> 
        <p class="location"></p>
            <p class="temp"></p>
        </div>


      <div class="currentWeather">
        <span class = "weather-description"></span>
        <span class="conditions"></span>
            <div class="info">
                <span class="rain"></span>
                <span class="wind"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>




    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/1.2/css/weather-icons.min.css);


@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    body{
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px
    }
    #weather_wrapper{
        width: 300px;
    }
    .weatherCard{
        width: 300px;
    }

}

body{
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7474BF 10%, #348AC7 90%);
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

#weather_wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 450px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.weatherCard{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    position: relative;
}
.currentTemp{
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
}
.temp:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.currentWeather{
    width: 180px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgb(237, 237, 237);
    margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.help{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.info{
  background: rgb(42, 178, 234);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
.temp{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.location{
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(237, 237, 237)
}
.conditions{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
.weather-description{
    margin-left: 59px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: absolute;
}

.wind {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .wind::after {
    display: block;
    content: '\f050';
    font-family: weathericons;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -26px;
  }
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hpsfj653/

I know that if I set a maximum-width then it should target all screens below that size. However, the only thing that really changes is the body width. I also considered setting the ´margin´ for the ´#weather_Wrapper´ and ´.WeatherCard´ to 0. However, that did not work.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you did not remove your left margin when responsive and you should follow css specificity.
For more details about css specificity

[See w3schools css specificity tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp)

you had used your media that does not follow specificity,

also you can try using **!important** it will work fine.

see the snippet below.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/1.2/css/weather-icons.min.css);




body{
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7474BF 10%, #348AC7 90%);
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

  
  @media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
  
 body{
  width: 300px!important;
  height: 150px!important;
 }
 #weather_wrapper{
  width: 100%!important;
    margin-left: 0px!important;
   
 }
 .weatherCard{
  width: 100%!important;
 }

}


#weather_wrapper{
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: 450px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.weatherCard{
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 position: relative;
}
.currentTemp{
 width: 220px;
 height: 200px;
 background: rgb(41, 41, 41);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
}
.temp:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.currentWeather{
 width: 180px;
 height: 200px;
 background: rgb(237, 237, 237);
 margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}
.help{
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 top: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.info{
  background: rgb(42, 178, 234);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
}
.temp{
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-top: 110px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 position: absolute;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.location{
 width: 120px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: 80px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 position: absolute;
 color: rgb(237, 237, 237)
}
.conditions{
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-left: 60px;
 position: absolute;
}
.weather-description{
 margin-left: 59px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 position: absolute;
}

.wind {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 30px;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 14px;
  }

  .wind::after {
 display: block;
 content: '\f050';
 font-family: weathericons;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-left: 75px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -26px;
  }
```

```html
  <body id="body">
    <div id="weather_wrapper">
   <div class="weatherCard">

      <div class="currentTemp">
        <p class = "help">Click on the temp to change units</p> 
        <p class="location"></p>
     <p class="temp"></p>
    </div>
      

      <div class="currentWeather">
        <span class = "weather-description"></span>
        <span class="conditions"></span>
     <div class="info">
      <span class="rain"></span>
      <span class="wind"></span>
     </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>




    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write the part with the media queries *after*  the other CSS rules (at the bottom), otherwise the regular rules will override the media queries, simply because they follow *after*  them and are still valid for the selectors they contain in *all* sizes.

Comment: Oh, that is a great point. I went ahead and updated it to the bottom. However, it still makes me horizontally scroll.

Comment: well, you are using fixed widths (i.e. fixed pixel values) for many of your elements (for example `#weather_wrapper`), which won't fit into smaller screens. In general, you should use percentage values and `max-width` settings instead (always depends on the particular situation, but as a general guideline).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need media queries in order to accomplish your goal. 
First, you should add the height to the **html** and **body** tags like this:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And second, you shouldn't use fixed margins at all. try to replace the #wheater_wrapper id with this:

```
#weather_wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The display flex will create a flex container that will adapt to any device width and the justify-content-center will center horizontally and the align-items-center will center vertically (this is the reason why we set the html and body tags height 100%).

Let me know if you have any doubt or trouble with this approach.